# How to model a header detail level granularity table alongside a header level fact table when a certain dimension is only applicable to the header?

Tags: powerbi, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I have the following model:

My dimensions are product, customer, DateTable

My fact tables is:

FactSales (columns: order num, prod_id, cust_id, date, num of items, total amount, cost of pkg, lineitemid, lineitemqty, lineitemprice). The granularity of this table is at the order detail level (so the order header data is repeated).

This is a star schema.

I have a requirement to add FactCharges (columns: order num, prod_id, cust_id, date, chargetype, chargeamt). The granularity is at the OrderHeader level.

**And the user must be able to drill through from the Sales to the Charges data.**

I am thinking to solve this by either of following approaches:

1. Create a new dimension table called Orders which will have distinct list of order nums. Then connect this to both FactSales and FactCharges on ord num.
2. Additionally I can include prodid, custid, date into the Orders dim and make this table sit between the dimensions and both facts.
3. Another way I'm thinking is to use something like TREATAS to create a virtual relationship on Ord Num between FactSales and FactCharges.

Is there a better pattern for this requirement?

Comment: This one is a bit more difficult to understand without model diagrams. What is the need for FactCharges? Is that info already in FactSales or is it completely different?

Comment: FactCharges has Ord Num, productid, customerid, and contains various charges for that order header. For example: order num 1 can have 3 charges (like warehouse charge, delivery charge, supplier charge). So each row has the charge breakdown by ord num, prodid and custid.

Comment: In that case, I'd be going for Option 1. Why is cost of pkg not also in FactCharges?

Comment: TREATAS is a good fall back option I use if the model is getting too complicated and it is a disconnected table that won't be heavily used. Or you can create a relationship but just make it inactive and then activate as required in the measure you have.

Comment: 1. How about my proposed solution wherein I make a new dimension containing distinct OrdNums, and then connect it to both Fact tables? This way they model remains a Star schema.

Comment: 2. In your comment above, you mention `create a relationship` - between what please?

Comment: I think the options I have are: 1. Shared dimension on OrdNum; 2. Inactive relation between FactSales and FactCharges, and use of CALCULATE/USERELATIONSHIP; 3. TREATAS. On what basis can I make a choice on this?

Comment: Don't connect your two fact tables as that will not be a star schema and performance will be terrible. I would select option 1 from your last comment and create a new dimension for OrdNums and relate that to both fact tables.

Comment: If you get any model ambiguity, you could make this relationship inactive and just activate as required in individual measures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256340/discussion-between-variable-and-davide-bacci).